# Laravel eloquent skip method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've came into a issue while using laravel eloquent ORM.
Basically, I'm obtaining the posts related to a user, as well his comments, however, I'm trying to integrate some kind of pagination(I only want to take 5 posts at a time).
While using the skip method, I'm always getting the following laravel error:

> Method skip does not exist.

Here's the code snippet I'm using actually.

```
$posts = $account->posts->skip($page * 5)->take(5);
```

Could anyone give me any kind of assistance?
The account model retrieve the posts models related to the user(Relationship), however, I would like to only received 5 posts at a time, to use it on ajax based requests.

Comment: One of the ways I've came across is to use the Posts model itself, without using the Account instantiated model, however I'm trying to avoid doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use `skip()` on a collection.

Try this instead:

```
$account->posts()->skip($page * 5)->take(5);
```

Or:

```
Account::with(['posts' => function($q) {
    $q->skip($page * 5)->take(5);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to integrate some kind of pagination

Why you don't using `paginate` in this case? Something like

```
$account->posts()->paginate(5);
```

Comment: I've came across with that solution, however the platform will be a API system.

Comment: And for what I've read in the laravel docs, pagination uses the page query variable(?page) from the http request, which somehow isn't suitable for my solution(AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I found another answer to be if you are using a laravel collection, you can use slice() instead of skip() -  Using code at the top you could also

```
$posts = $account->posts->slice($page * 5)->take(5);
```

More Info

[Laracasts Slice](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-skip-one-element-from-collection)